# ¿Como podria borrar una linea ej: "posicion 6" en un archivo .txt o en una cadena String?

Tags: java, android

Intente varias maneras  pero no logro hacerlo. una de ellas seria esta y me da error:

```
try {
    java.io.BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new 
    FileWriter("Archivo.txt"));
    bufferedWriter.append("Esto es la linea 1");
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.append("Esto es la linea 2");
    bufferedWriter.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

La otra manera que probe es esta:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fichero = args[0];
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fichero);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String linea;
        while((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(linea);

        fr.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excepcion leyendo fichero "+ fichero + ": " + e);
    }
}
```

pero me lee el fichero entero.

Comment: Antonio  main(String args[])  no es usado en Android,agrega más datos, donde se supone agregarías tu archivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando java puedes eliminar una linea de esta forma usando `BufferedReader` para leer el archivo y sus lineas, al realizar la comparación el archivo sin la linea se escribiría en el archivo definido por `BufferedWriter` , recuerda que en android no puedes definir rutas de tu pc:

```
 String lineToRemove = "posicion 6";

   File inputFile = new File("C:\\Data\\archivo.txt");
   File outputFile = new File("C:\\Data\\archivo_nuevo.txt");

    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {                        
        if(currentLine.trim().equals(lineToRemove)){ 
            continue;
        }
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }       

    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```